# Regex to extract text within exact given function

Tags: regex

I am reading text from a `.config` file and then I have a long string where I need to extract a text which matches the below given pattern. `.config` file has 2 functions defined (`input and filter`)

This is the text extracted from the `.config` file

```
input {
  name: "abc",
  age: "20"
}

filter {
  name: "pqr",
  age: "25"
}
```

I need to extract only the text within the filter function including the filter text itself

**expected output**

```
filter {
  name: "pqr",
  age: "25"
}
```

Here I have written a regex where I can extract all the text within the `{ }` parenthesis.

[Created Regex](https://regex101.com/r/0SHjXz/1)

At the moment it extracts text within the overall file. Anyone can help me to update the regex to extract only the filter function with its name by updating the regex ( we need to consider both the intermediate space exist and non-exist behavior as well)

scenario 1 - space between filter text and the parenthesis

```
filter {
  name: "pqr",
  age: "25"
}
```

and

scenario 2 - no space between filter text and the parenthesis

```
filter{
  name: "pqr",
  age: "25"
}
```

Comment: can you please try this //(filter\s*\{([^)]+)\})igm

Comment: (filter.+?}) should do

Comment: If there can be braces inside the scope of "filter", then you should not use a regular expression. What language do you use? Is there a package, module or library that can parse this text for your and return a structured object?

Comment: Its just  a logstash pipeline configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex which will match your filter block and also the space between `filter` and `{...}` is optional and will match with or without space.

```
^filter\s*\{[^{}]+\}$
```

Notice: I have enabled the `m` flag in the demo, so you will need to enable it in your programming language or use inline modifier before the regex like this `(?m)^filter\s*\{[^{}]+\}$`

**Regex Explanation:**

- `^filter` - Starts matching the text with filter
- `\s*` - Allows for matching optional whitespace
- `\{` - Matches literal `{`
- `[^{}]+` - Matches one or more any character except `{` or `}`
- `\}$` - Matches the closing `}` and marks end of input

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0SHjXz/8)**

Comment: this works fine. But is there any way that I can use the text "filter" exactly in the regex. Because there could be other functions available in the file and cannot guarantee that it will be the 2nd always

Comment: @SameeraManorathna: Updated my post. Let me know if you have any queries further.

Comment: Will there be any way I can avoid the except { or } behavior. So I can extract the filter function even there are brackets within it. e.g. - filter { grok {} } cannot be identified here. Will there be a way to still extract text of the filter function even there are intermediate nested functions

Comment: @SameeraManorathna: If you don't want to use `[^{}]+` then you can use `.*?` which would match as less content as possible, before matching the ending `}`, OR you can use `.*` which would capture any character greedily and only stop at last matching `}`. Non-greedy `.*?` should be desirable IMO.

Comment: This does not work for me. I have built this ^filter\s*\{[^*]+\} where it goes until the * is not presented in the text. But I need to remove the except part. can you do that ?

Comment: Can you share the text you are working with? Better in a regex101 demo url?

Comment: I have updated the regex. https://regex101.com/r/0SHjXz/9 Now I need to extract the all text within filter function with the filter text itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192416/discussion-between-sameera-manorathna-and-pushpesh-kumar-rajwanshi).